# adding custom progress bar in android webview

Tags: android

I need a progress bar at the centre of my android webview it must be shown before the page loads and hides when the page is loaded. How can it be done? Can anyone help me?

This is my code for webview:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String title;
final String url;

if (!Datacon.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {

if (extras != null) {
    title = extras.getString("title");
    url = extras.getString("url");
    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(title);
    final WebView myWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); 
    loadingProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal); 

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

Button refresh = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.but2);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);

        }
    });

} 
}}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override a couple of more methods in the `WebViewClient` :

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

I'm assuming `loadingProgressBar` is a class field.

PS: As a side note I believe you overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is unnecessary. The default behaviour is to load the url, as you instruct it to do.

Comment: thanku nw i get it.but it is showing at the side of the page.how can i display it exactly at the  centre of the page.

Comment: That's a different question, but check out the gravity and layout_gravity properties of either the containing layout view or the view itself

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initializeProgressBar() {
if (progressBar == null){
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressBar.setMessage(Constants.LOADING_MESSAGE);
progressBar.setCancelable(false);
}
}

Handler peogressBar = new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
try{
switch (msg.what) {
case 1:
initializeProgressBar();
if(!progressBar.isShowing())
progressBar.show();
break;
case 2:
if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
progressBar.dismiss();
progressBar = null;

}
break;
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
};
};



wv_graphLink = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_graphLink);
wv_graphLink.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv_graphLink.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv_graphLink.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wv_graphLink.setInitialScale(1);
wv_graphLink.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv_graphLink.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
// wv_graphLink.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
// wv_graphLink.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
peogressBar.sendEmptyMessage(1);
wv_graphLink.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

if(progress == 100){
peogressBar.sendEmptyMessage(2);


}

}
});

wv_graphLink.loadUrl("Your url");
```